# Unpack a bit from a binary string with Ruby

Tags: ruby, binary, unpack

I'm using `String::unpack` to unpack a bunch of ints and double from a binary stream. How can I unpack a single bit from that bitstream? I cannot find a specific directive for decoding single bits with unpack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unpacking can go down to the byte level. You could read an unsigned byte by using the ['C' format](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.6/classes/String.html#M000688) and then you can use bitmasks to query individual maps.

Comment: Do I risk going out of bounds when the bit is at the end of the stream and reading 7 more bits using the 'C' directive?

Comment: @aliekens I don't think so. By the time the stream gets into to ruby it must consist of bytes. There no such thing as a partial byte. If the data is only 9 bits then it will be represented as 2 bytes and the rest will be padded with zeros.